# Will molasses of grape be considered wine (and thus haram) after its expiry date?

Tags: halal-haram, food, alcohol

It is a long time that I have molasses of grape (as a permissible drink or eatable food). But I kept it for a long time and did not drink it. At the moment, I'm worried it has changed to wine (to some extent or even completely) after this time. Will it have the ruling of wine after its expiry date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its intoxicating then it is haram. It is not simply because of its chemical composition, but because it has an intoxicating effect. Eating food cooked in wine is not intoxicating, so think about it :)

### Surat Al-Ma'idah [5:90]

### *O you who have believed, indeed, intoxicants, gambling, [sacrificing on] stone altars [to other than Allah ], and divining arrows are but defilement from the work of Satan, so avoid it that you may be successful.*

There are hundreds of hadiths that support this answer, but there is one hadith from Ahmad that doesnt. In fact most refer to drinks not as a composite part of food. That one from Ahmad states more or less that anything intoxicating in large amounts is prohibited in small amounts. Since alcohol exists in the gut of every person as a by product of bacteria everyone and everything is in a questionable state. This is just one contradiction to common sense. Following the Ahmad hadith its haram to use rubbing alcohol for a cut.

*So this answer is not as clean cut as I thought, but I still stand by it and live by it. I think it takes some thoughtful judgement, but the Quran is clear. Thank God.*

Comment: Basically you are wrong. “Whatever intoxicates in large quantities, a little of it is haraam.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 1865; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi. But regarding question i don't know ow wine or alcohol is made so i will not add an asnwer

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification; they are not intended for argument and debate, and especially not for protracted discussion of controversial points.